# Which OpenCV function is suitable for contour detection in binary, single channel images of uint8 type?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have a normal RGB image that looks like this : [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bszKh.jpg)

I did the following preprocessing steps on this image:

- extracted color plane (blue) using cv.split()
- adjusted brightness, contrast and gamma(with values of alpha, beta and gamma)
- applied binary thresholding

this is the result after preprocessing : [preprocessed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5gH9.jpg)

As you can see, there are 26 distinct objects on this image. I need to detect these contours on the image and find some geometric properties of each contour. However, I am not sure what functions would be suitable for accurately detecting the contours. This is a binary, single channel image(blue) of uint8 type.

I tried the following two functions along with results:

`contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

`for contour in contours: blob_properties.append(contour)`

```
[array([[[  0,   0]],

       [[  0, 474]],

       [[759, 474]],

       [[759,   0]]], dtype=int32)]
```

and

`contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image=image, mode = cv2.RETR_TREE,method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`

`for contour in contours: blob_properties.append(contour)`

```
[array([[[0, 0]],

       [[0, 1]],

       [[0, 2]],

       ...,

       [[3, 0]],

       [[2, 0]],

       [[1, 0]]], dtype=int32), array([[[ 60, 424]],

       [[ 61, 423]],

       [[ 62, 423]],

.
.
.
       [465, 163]],

       [[466, 162]],

       [[467, 161]],

       [[468, 160]]], dtype=int32)] (long 2D array with 42 rows)
```

I am not sure how these functions are creating these arrays. Also, whether or not it makes sense to use these functions for a binary, single channel image(blue) of uint8 type. I am ideally expecting an array containing 26 rows along with all the other values the contour detection returns.

Can somebody please guide me on this topic?

Thanks

EDIT : minimum reproducible example

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('input_image.jpg')
(R,G,B) = cv2.split(image)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(B, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
blob_properties = []
#apply cv2.findContours() function here
```

Comment: I think with RETR_TREE you get a hierarchy for each match. You could filter the contours by area, length,...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You do not show a minimum reproducible example.  You do not show your imports, so how can we reproduce your code? Where do you get blob_properties?

Comment: I am adding the imports. That should be enough for a minimum reproducible example. Also, blob_properties is an empty array, until we start appending items to it.

Comment: @fmw42 I have added the imports required for a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: You do not define or show blob_properties!

Comment: The contours go around the objects, which are the white connected regions on the black background. Your segmentation result is inverted, making the sky the object and the birds some holes in the object. Just invert the image before getting contours.

Comment: @fmw42 I have now defined blob_properties as an empty array before calling cv2.findContours()

Comment: @CrisLuengo Applying inverted thresholding really helped! I have started to get near accurate results! Thanks!

Comment: What are you putting into blob_properties?  What are the arrays that you show -- are they just the contours?  What do you want to measure as properties from the contours?

Comment: @fmw42 For now, I am putting the entire contours into 'blob_properties' as a starting point. But my objective is to measure some geometric properties of each blob namely 'First Pixel X', 'First Pixel Y' and 'Area'. I consider that as an independent problem that I can approach, now that I have started getting near accurate results for the total count of blobs on the image.

Comment: @Sa'adMuHammad You could check Hu Moments too if you want to differentiate the shapes of the birds.

Comment: If you want statistics, see cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats()